# Port on Azure DC VM can not be reached from outside network even it is opened on the local firewall and azure portal

Tags: networking, firewall, azure, port

I installed Op5 (Nagios) monitoring server on CentOs 6.8 in Hyper-V environment on our Local server with public IP and I could monitor smoothly all the servers on Hyper-V locally and the servers on Azure cloud except one server on Azure which is windows server 2012 R with a domain controller , I have opened the require ports on Azure portal and locally on the DC virtual machine's firewall and I used the same configuration with the other servers on Azure and all are working well accept the domain controller ?

I got "CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds. for all the services"

I test the working servers on Azure for port 5666 and it is all working well and I tried to test the DC with port 5666 from outside the network but it can not be reached even I opened the ports in the same way I opened it to the other servers on Azure? the ports are opened on the two-tier , on Azure firewall and on the DC machine firewall.

on Op5 configuration file already set up the allowed hosts to IP of the Op5 monitor server.

any hints ?

Comment: if you run a netstat, is the port open on the box?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as CtrlDot has mentioned above, please check if the service has been bound to the port.

If the service is running and being bound to the port correctly, you may try to perform a network capture on your Domain Controller to check if the request from the monitoring server has been received by the Domain Controller.

If the request is logged by the network capture tool, it means that there is something on the server prevent the service from receiving the request. (Maybe some security software?)

If the request isn't captured by the network capture tool, then there may be something wrong with the Azure platform. I would suggest that you may open a ticket with Azure support team, so that they will troubleshoot this issue with you on the Azure side.